# Duvida com teste mongodb

Tags: sql, mongodb, nosql

Sou iniciante no mongo estou com uma duvida com select/consulta.

Eu preciso fazer uma consulta que busque na base *yoda* e na `collection configuracoes` que retorne todos os documentos que possuem a chave `tipoRecibo` com o valor igual a *gps*.

Sei que tenho que usar

```
$filter
= array
```

porem da *collection* pra frente me pegou, se alguém me dar um super help, agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/) para rodar uma query que obtém documentos de uma coleção MongoDB. Todas as queries no MongoDB tem como escopo, uma única coleção.

Queries podem retornar todos os documentos de uma coleção, ou apenas os documentos que coincidam com um determinado filtro ou critério.

Você pode especificar o filtro ou critério, em um documento e enviá-lo como parâmetro ao método [`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/).

O método [`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/) retorna resultados de um cursor, um objeto iterável que emite documentos.

No *mongo shell* conectado com uma instância *mongod*, alterne para o banco `yoda`:

```
use yoda
```

Para obter todos os documentos da coleção, você pode chamar o método [`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/) sem um documento de critérios. Por exemplo, a seguinte operação obtém todos os documentos na coleção `configuracoes`:

```
db.configuracoes.find()
```

O *result set* contém todos os documentos na coleção `configuracoes`.

Para definir condições de igualdade, basta associar o campo com o valor:

```
{<campo>: <valor>}
```

No teu caso, você pode fazer assim:

```
db.configuracoes.find({"tipoRecibo": "gps"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara você está com necessidade de ver todas as operações mais básicas do mongo eu te sugiro estas referências aqui, elas tem me ajudado bastante no meu dia à dia.

http://www.w3ii.com/pt/mongodb/mongodb_query_document.html

https://github.com/Webschool-io/MongoDb-ebook/tree/master/pt-br

O mongo é sensacional você vai ver com o tempo. Sucesso!!